# Defining infinite list in Haskell of same int, which way?

Tags: list, haskell

Defining infinite list in Haskell:

```
[1,1..] => [1,1,1,..]
```

Or, the circular way:

```
lst=1:lst
```

Is the first defined the same as the second? If not, which one is the preferred way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want [`repeat`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=repeat) where the definition is equivalent to your second implementation.

The `[1,1..]` notation in your first example is syntactic sugar for the `enumFrom*` prelude functions. Use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 6):

`repeat` / `1:lst` are better, they don't require any extra calculation but `[1,1..]` does:

```
[1,1..] = enumFromThen 1 1 = en 1
            where en n = n : en (n + nΔ)
                  nΔ = 1-1 = 0
```

so it always needs to perform the extra `1+0`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unlucky, your first infinite list will use an infinite amount of memory. So use your second infinite list (or, if you'd prefer an anonymous infinite list, use [`repeat`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3arepeat) from the Prelude).

---

A demonstration. Perhaps leave `watch free -m` running in another window while doing this.

```
$ cat so.hs
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

with :: String -> [Int] -> IO ()
with s xs
   = do putStrLn $ "Summing part of a " ++ s
        theSum <- evaluate $ sum (take 100000000 xs)
        firstElem <- evaluate $ head xs
        putStrLn $ "sum $ take 100000000 [" ++ show firstElem ++ "...] is " ++ show theSum

main :: IO ()
main
   = do with "call to repeat" (repeat 1)
        putStr "Press return to continue..."
        hFlush stdout
        getLine
        with "list comprehension" [1,1..]

$ ghc -O --make so.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
$ ./so
Summing part of a call to repeat
sum $ take 100000000 [1...] is 100000000
Press return to continue...
Summing part of a list comprehension
^C
```

The first summation runs in constant space. The second summation eats up memory, so I interrupt it before it causes my laptop to swap.

In this simple case we could avoid the space leak by calculating `firstElem` before calculating `theSum`, but in a real world application this may not be possible, or at least difficult to track down. Better to avoid it by using `repeat`.

(A note on optimisation: if we don't pass the `-O` flag to `ghc` then [*`sum`*](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#sum) will space leak during both summations. It would not be hard to rewrite `sum = foldl' (+) 0` so that it did not space leak even without `-O`. I do not know what considerations lead to the current implementation instead.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the first might use infinite memory?

Comment: I assume because each '1' might actually be allocated and take up a few bytes, whereas in the second case, you just have a single '1' and a single pointer, no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, both are unfolds, but the `let` and `repeat` variants are better, because the `enumFrom` variant goes through actual enumeration, so useless arithmetic is involved.